# TeeChart Print Margin %

Tags: vcl, teechart

I am using TChartPreviewer to print a TChart.
The Margin% defaults to T35, R15, B35 & L15.
How/where do I change them all to 5 please?

Regards & TIA,

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained at the *Panel* section in *Tutorial 2 - Chart display properties*, available at TeeChart's program group. You need to use the following Runtime properties: *Chart1.MarginTop*, *Chart1.MarginLeft*, *Chart1.MarginRight* and *Chart1.MarginBottom*.

for example:

```
  Chart1.MarginTop := 5;
```